# Keys that fit no lock

Tags: riddle

You wake up in a cell, with no memory of what happened to you, and how you ended up here. The cell has four doors, and above each there's a "N", "S", "E" and "W", which you assume tell you the direction they're facing.

Next to you lies a paper, and on it you find the word "MOVE", an apparently useless line of numbers, "422448886886688", and a Map of your current surroundings (it's an 11x11 sized maze). The centered chamber is marked with a red "X".

What route do you take to escape?

Note: You assume that something bad (death, most likely) will happen if you take a wrong route.

Hint 1:

> The line of numbers is not as useless as it seems.

Hint 2:

> "Move" has the same meaning as "Shift".

Hint 3:

> The titles is a hint, too.

Comment: Um, I would look at the map and figure out how to get out of the maze.  That's what maps are for.

Comment: @Kevin It's my first "question" here, I knew that I'd mess up some way atleast :D The map only shows a basic layer of 11x11 squares + the X, nothing else, neither end nor route.

Comment: Absent the word "keys" in the title, is there any reason to assume 2 is down (as on a computer keyboard) rather than up (as on a telephone)?

Comment: (1) Why bother saying that the cell is dark if there’s enough light to read the paper and the map, and the illumination level is irrelevant to the riddle?  (2) If the doors “*presumably* are faced north, west, east and south,” how do you tell which is which?

Comment: I found this too easy - 30 seconds to solve it and then realise there was already 2 correct answers :/

Comment: How do you know which way is north?

Comment: For anyone who plays roguelikes or DROD it's way too obvious but it gave me a smile :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> 2, 4, 6, 8 are keys on your keyboard numpad
>  2 is South (down)
>  4 is West (left)
>  6 is East (right)
>  8 is North (top)
>
>  422448886886688 is the sequence of directions you have to follow

Map :

> 422448886886688
>
>  $$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline&&&&&15&&&&&\\\hline&&&&&14&&&&&\\\hline&&&11&12&13&&&&&\\\hline&&&10&&&&&&&\\\hline&&8&9&&&&&&&\\\hline&&7&&1&X&&&&&\\\hline&&6&&2&&&&&&\\\hline&&5&4&3&&&&&&\\\hline&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline\end{array}$$

Hint 1

> The line of numbers is the directions

Hint 2

> You can use Shift on your keyboard. Some numpads have arrows on 2,4,6,8 when used with shift.

Hint 3

> "Keys" in the title refer to keyboard

Comment: 100% accurate! :)

Comment: And how do you know which door is West to start off with?

Comment: @abligh You must not have magnetoreception :)

Comment: Why can't it be keypad on phones? The north-south will be reversed

Comment: @justhalf the shift hint : on computer keypads, shift + 2/4/6/8 = arrow

Comment: Hmm, but that's on the hint. Without the hint it can still be both.

Answer (score 10):

I think the solution is

> [image: Solution]

Reasoning: Keys that fit no locks stands for

> keys on a keyboard, specifically the numpad

and MOVE means

> move in the direction of the arrow on the numpad key corresponding to the number
>  [image: Nunmpad]
>  2 = down
>  4 = left
>  8 = up
>  6 = right

Comment: You are completely right! :)